# What is meant by bloopers and marathon?

Tags: terminology

I have seen TV shows marathon episodes and bloopers such as:

- Leverage Marathon
- X-Files Bloopers

Are they things like credits or previews? What are their meanings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the name suggests, a **[marathon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon_%28television%29)** is the sequential broadcast of a single or a number of related television programs for a long period of time; up to days if it is a TV series with many episodes.

The most common reasons for a network to run a TV show marathon are:

- to celebrate the acquisition of a series,
- to lead into a highly anticipated episode of a series (such as a return from a hiatus or a series finale),
- when well known star of a show retires or passes away (this is particularly popular on networks such as [TV Land](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_Land) and [Game Show Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Show_Network), which specialize in [reruns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rerun)),
- to celebrate a holiday, or
- to inexpensively counterprogram against more popular programs such as the Super Bowl

Some of the longest running marathons are the two [Twilight Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_(1959_TV_series)) marathons that air on the SyFy in the United States on New Years Day and Independence Day.

A **[blooper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blooper)** is a short sequence of a film or video production, usually a deleted scene, containing a mistake made by a member of the cast or crew.

The term blooper was popularized in the 1950s in a series of record albums entitled Pardon My Blooper, in which the definition of a blooper is thus given by the record series' narrator: "*Unintended indiscretions before microphone and camera*."

Bloopers are often the subject of television shows or are occasionally revealed during the credit sequence at the end of comedy movies.

Answer (score 10):

A marathon is a collection of shows from the television show run one after another, mostly in order of release, such as a full season run together.

Bloopers are generally mistakes caught during filming that would tend to be funny (i.e. trips and falls, or really dangerous and bloody accidents, or unfortunate script mispronunciation, especially if it comes out sounding sexual).